# Angular 2, ngOnChanges, ngDoCheck

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, lifecycle

Hello folks i have come to you with many thoughs, i would like to talk about something i cannot get.

## Simple service studies

So we have here one service who is triggered by a component.

This is a simple service who commit an observable element when it get triggered :

```
return this.subject.asObservable();
```

Then we have a component getting this :

```
this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
```

Ok until now everything is ok.
This logic is include into a component , his selector name is `<alert></alert>`

## Nested Component

Here we have another component with this `<alert></alert>`.

```
<div class="article-page-container">
  <alert></alert>
  <ul *ngIf="!alert" class="page-nav-container">
    <li *ngFor="let page of pageArray" (click)="pageHandlerEvent(page)" [ngClass]="{ 'page-active': page == pageActive}">{{ page }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Did you get it ? What i am trying to do is when the nested component is getting an alert it should turn of the page nav class.

I have found one solution, this is not a problem about how to makes it works, but find the right one, made something that people will be proud of ?

## ngDoCheck

Do i need to say more ? It's ugly , i get like 1000000000 useless check, but it will works.

## ngDoChanges

Should only happens when something inside my component is actually getting 'change', right ?

So i have try this :

```
<div class="article-page-container">
  <alert (alertOn)="toggleNav($event)"></alert>
  <ul *ngIf="!alert" class="page-nav-container">
    <li *ngFor="let page of pageArray" (click)="pageHandlerEvent(page)" [ngClass]="{ 'page-active': page == pageActive}">{{ page }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Everytime an alert is triggered i do a simple `this.alertOn.emit(true)`,

However ngOnChanges doesn't work at all. And this will result with :

```
core.umd.js:3493 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

## Other tests

- I have try to include direclty this service into the container (same
  issue)
- I have move the alert outside the component, using an Input with
  ngOnChanges work (another solution, but looks likes more i'm avoiding
  my problem more than finding a solution)

I know you guys are great, so if you have any idea about what should be done in a 'correct way'.

Have an awesome day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving the

```
this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
```

subscription to your parent container, and then sending the message as an input through

```
<alert [message]=message></alert>
```

this way you can also include some logic to change an display flag boolean for your page-nav-container in the subscribe function

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: Well once I have try, even if it works it breaks the logic behind the fact i would like to have give order even from an other component than the parent, however i have found a solution (which I think it's better, i have updated my original post)

Answer (score 0):

So here the result i found that looks great !

```
@ViewChild(AlertComponent) AlertComponent: AlertComponent; 

.... 

ngAfterContentChecked () {
  this.alert = (this.AlertComponent.message) ? true : false;
}
```

Simple, it doesn't need to change the logic also it will not loose any perf compare to ngDocheck() with it's 10000k tests ...